# How can I open an iPhoto Library on a PC?

Tags: windows-10, iphoto

I saved an iPhoto Library off a Mac circa 2006. I'm now trying to open the iPhoto library on a PC, but it doesn't seem that straight forward?

Is it possible?

What do I need to do?

Here is some extra information if it helps

This is what the AlbumData.xml looks like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Application Version</key>
    <string>2.0.1 (3E8)</string>
    <key>Archive Path</key>
    <string>/Users/kate/Pictures/iPhoto Library</string>
    <key>List of Albums</key>
    <array>
```

And this is what the file system looks like:

[image]

Comment: You've already strictly 'opened' it. It's really a folder that appears as just a file on a Mac, but not on Windows. What are you actually trying to extract from it? The database itself will be of no use, it's an sql & not the simplest of formats. The pictures will be in those folders.

Comment: I'm trying to get the photo's out of it. It I know SQL, so if I knew how to load it up into a database ..... maybe I can figure it out? :-D

Comment: Oh I see, I can see the images, I didn't realise this, I tried some other random folder and they were empty, but now I can see that there are in the year folders!

Comment: Yup. That looks like a very early version of the Library, before there was even an 'originals' folder let alone a 'Masters' so photos are all just in their date folder.

Comment: Yes thanks, I have the Originals folder. It is quite straightforward now I see it. It is quite weird. It has an Album folder which has a bunch of .jpg files. I tried to open them as images... but in fact they are text files pointing to the location of the image in the "date" folder.

Comment: It's all linked through the rather oblique sqlite database. It's really not for the faint-hearted. I found a forensic breakdown of the iOS 12 version, but it changes per device & per OS… https://www.forensicmike1.com/2019/05/02/ios-photos-sqlite-forensics/ If all you want are the photos, they're the only things really in 'plain'.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhoto library is a normal folder you can open in Windows or any other system. On macOS it appear like a file in the Finder, but really it's a folder.

Your photos will be in the sub-directories.

The other file such as `Dir.data`, `Library.data` or `AlbumData.xml` contain meta data about your libraries, you don't need to access this informations to.